# Cambiar color texto javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero cambiar varias etiquetas h1 y h3 de color cuando paso sobre ellos y de esta forma solo me cambia uno, cada uno tiene su ID.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Ejercicio 2 - Eventos</title><meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
        body {font-family:Arial;}
    </style>


</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="enlace">Novedades</h1>
    <p>Aquí presentamos las novedades del sitio.</p>
    <h3 id="enlace">Lanzamos el producto X-FASHION</h3>
    <p>Este producto permite estirar la piel hasta dejarla como la de un bebé.</p>
    <div><img src="https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14067484_1158738217503225_7524550350452532772_n.png?oh=b3024e965f9df64fba062e265fb0fcd1&oe=590C71CE" title="Imagen del producto" alt="imagen producto x-fashion" /></div>
    <h3 id="enlace">Mejoramos el producto T-MOTION</h3>
    <p>Hemos lanzado una nueva versión del producto T-MOTION</p>
    <div><img src="http://cheerskills.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Screen-shot-2012-03-25-at-6.14.58-PM.png" title="Imagen del proudcto tmotion" alt="imagen producto tmotion" /></div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="DWEC_T06_Ejercicio2.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Tengo este codigo Javascript

```
    //Funcion que cambia el color de los enlaces a naranja al pasar por encima

document.getElementById("enlace").addEventListener("mouseover", porencima);
document.getElementById("enlace").addEventListener("mouseout", alquitar);



function porencima() {

    document.getElementById("enlace").style.color = "orange";

}

function alquitar() {

    document.getElementById("enlace").style.color = "brown";

}
```

Comment: En realidad no tienes ningún enlace en tu código de ejemplo

Comment: Cierto, me confundi pero quiero que haga eso

Comment: Prueba la respuesta a ver si te resulta

Comment: Tu código no es correcto porque tienes varios elementos con la misma id "enlace", cámbialos por **class="enlace"** y seguramente funcionará; aunque te recomiendo hacerlo como sugiere **Hector Lara** en su respuesta, solo con CSS.

Comment: Si cambiara las ID por class, ¿que deberia usar en vez de getElementById?

Comment: para obtener elementos por clase puedes utilizar document.getElementsByClassName("clase");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes tener más de un elemento con el mismo `id`, por lo que si quisieras agrupar elementos con ciertas propiedades es recomendable usar `class` o [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Basándome en [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140333/cambiar-color-texto-javascript#comment262178_140337) y usando [delegación de eventos](https://ed.team/blog/como-usar-la-delegacion-de-eventos-en-javascript) (`eg: Event delegation`), una solución usando `class` podría ser la siguiente:

#### Ejemplo

```js
// Cuando el mouse pasa por encima de algún elemento
window.addEventListener('mouseover', function(evt) {
  // Si elemento tiene la clase `enlace`
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('enlace')) {
    evt.target.style.color = 'orange';
  }
});

// Cuando el mouse salga de encima de algún elemento
window.addEventListener('mouseout', function(evt) {
  // Si elemento tiene la clase `enlace`
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('enlace')) {
    evt.target.style.color = 'brown';
  }
});
```

```html
<h1 class="enlace">Novedades</h1>
<p>Aquí presentamos las novedades del sitio.</p>
<h3 class="enlace">Lanzamos el producto X-FASHION</h3>
<p>Este producto permite estirar la piel hasta dejarla como la de un bebé.</p>
<div><img src="https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14067484_1158738217503225_7524550350452532772_n.png?oh=b3024e965f9df64fba062e265fb0fcd1&oe=590C71CE" title="Imagen del producto" alt="imagen producto x-fashion" /></div>
<h3 id="enlace">Mejoramos el producto T-MOTION</h3>
<p>Hemos lanzado una nueva versión del producto T-MOTION</p>
<div><img src="http://cheerskills.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Screen-shot-2012-03-25-at-6.14.58-PM.png" title="Imagen del proudcto tmotion" alt="imagen producto tmotion" /></div>
```

Comment: Esto era lo que quería, gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Primero : creas las funciones y la llamas en los eventos necesarios en cada elemento **onmouseover = cuando el mouse se pone encima**, **onmouseout = cuando el mouse se retira del elemento.**

```js
function porencima(x) {
 x.style.color = "orange";
}

function alquitar(x) {
x.style.color = "brown";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="enlace" onmouseover="porencima(this)" onmouseout="alquitar(this)">Novedades</h1>
<p>Aquí presentamos las novedades del sitio.</p>
<h3 class="enlace" onmouseover="porencima(this)" onmouseout="alquitar(this)">Lanzamos el producto X-FASHION</h3>
<p>Este producto permite estirar la piel hasta dejarla como la de un bebé.</p>
<div><img src="https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14067484_1158738217503225_7524550350452532772_n.png?oh=b3024e965f9df64fba062e265fb0fcd1&oe=590C71CE" title="Imagen del producto" alt="imagen producto x-fashion" /></div>
<h3 class="enlace" onmouseover="porencima(this)" onmouseout="alquitar(this)">Mejoramos el producto T-MOTION</h3>
<p>Hemos lanzado una nueva versión del producto T-MOTION</p>
<div><img src="http://cheerskills.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Screen-shot-2012-03-25-at-6.14.58-PM.png" title="Imagen del proudcto tmotion" alt="imagen producto tmotion" /></div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="DWEC_T06_Ejercicio2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lo se, pero en este ejercicio en concreto debo utilizar addEventListener.

Comment: ¿No existe alguna forma de cambiar de color todas las etiquetas h1, por ejemplo?

Comment: Claro que si existen maneras

Answer (score 3):

En un principio estas asignando varios **ID** a distintos tags de HTML recuerda que los ID son únicos para un solo tag, es decir solo un elemento h1 puede contener id="enlace" si quieres utilizar el mismo identificado para distintos elementos debes usar para **CLASS** es decir que quedaria **class="enlace"**. 
Ya que no utilizamos id tampoco puedes usar  **document.getElementById()** , debes usar **document.getElementsByClassName()**.
El problema de utilizar getElementsByClassName es que nos devuelve un arreglo de todos los elementos que tengan esa clase, osea que si tenemos dos elementos con una clase "enlace" 
**Ejemplo**: `<h1 class="enlace">soy h1</h1>  <h3 class="enlace">Soy h3</h3>`
El metodo getElementsByClassName nos devolvera ambos objetos en forma de arreglo. Entonces deberemos referenciar a cual queremos cambiarle el color.
Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que estoy hablando :P

```js
//Obtenemos todos los elementos con la clase "enlace"
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("enlace");

//Recorremos el arreglo con todos los elementos, asignando a cada uno los listener.
for(var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++){
    elementos[i].addEventListener("mouseover", porencima);
    elementos[i].addEventListener("mouseout", alquitar);
}

//Al usar this hacemos referencia al objeto que invoco la funcion
function porencima() {
    this.style.color = "orange";
}

function alquitar() {
    this.style.color = "brown";
}
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Ejercicio 2 - Eventos</title><meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
        body {font-family:Arial;}
    </style>


</head>
<body>

    <h1 class="enlace">Novedades</h1>
    <p>Aquí presentamos las novedades del sitio.</p>
    <h3 class="enlace">Lanzamos el producto X-FASHION</h3>
    <p>Este producto permite estirar la piel hasta dejarla como la de un bebé.</p>
    <div><img src="https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14067484_1158738217503225_7524550350452532772_n.png?oh=b3024e965f9df64fba062e265fb0fcd1&oe=590C71CE" title="Imagen del producto" alt="imagen producto x-fashion" /></div>
    <h3 class="enlace">Mejoramos el producto T-MOTION</h3>
    <p>Hemos lanzado una nueva versión del producto T-MOTION</p>
    <div><img src="http://cheerskills.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Screen-shot-2012-03-25-at-6.14.58-PM.png" title="Imagen del proudcto tmotion" alt="imagen producto tmotion" /></div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="DWEC_T06_Ejercicio2.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Otra manera seria hacerlo con CSS seria mas sencillo pero bueno si tienes que hacerlo con js ahi esta la solucion.
Tambien te respondo a esto